# Possible mistakes in a proof of the equivalence of Axiom of Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, axiom-of-choice

In previous post [Is this Theorem equivalent to Axiom of Choice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750388/is-this-theorem-equivalent-to-axiom-of-choice/), I asked whether it is possible to prove **(the Theorem** $\implies$ **Axiom of Choice)**. I received a proof in Noah's answer. I have a question regarding his proof, but he seems to be busy and unable to respond to my doubts. As a result, I post a new thread here.

My questions:

1. For $S_a=\{A,B,C\}\cup \{(x,a)\}$ and $S_b=\{A,B,D\}\cup \{(y,b)\}$, but $(x,a)=D$ and $(y,b)=C$. Thus $S_a = S_b$, while $a \neq b$. How can "*$S_a\not=S_b$ whenever $a\not=b$.*" as Noah said?
2. Please explain why Noah *"Fix some $x$ such that $\langle x, a\rangle\not\in\bigcup\mathcal{F}$ for any $a\in\bigcup\mathcal{F}$"*. I think it should be *$\langle x, a\rangle\not\in\mathcal{F}$ for any $a\in\bigcup\mathcal{F}$* so that $\langle x, a\rangle$ is not equal to any $f'\in \mathcal{F}$ and therefore $\langle x, a\rangle$ is a distinct indicator for $S_a$.
3. I also present two other proofs at the end. Please have a look at them and check whether they contain any error!

Thank you so much!

---

**Axiom of Choice:** Let $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of non-empty disjoint sets. Then there exists a choice function $f:\mathcal{F} \to \bigcup \mathcal{F}$ such that $f(A) \in A$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

**The Theorem:** For any set $\mathcal{F}$, there exists a function $g:\bigcup \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$ such that $a \in g(a)$ for all $a \in \bigcup \mathcal{F}$.

**Noah's verbatim answer:**

> Yes, the principle you've written is equivalent to AC.
>
> Suppose I have a family $\mathcal{F}$ of nonempty disjoint sets for which I want to construct a choice function. Fix some $x$ such that $\langle x, a\rangle\not\in\bigcup\mathcal{F}$ for any $a\in\bigcup\mathcal{F}$.  For $a\in\bigcup\mathcal{F}$, let $S_a=\{f\in\mathcal{F}: a\in f\}\cup\{\langle x, a\rangle\}$. *Note that the second term here means $S_a\not=S_b$ whenever $a\not=b$.*
>
> Now consider the set $X=\bigcup_{a\in \bigcup\mathcal{F}}S_a$, and apply your principle to it to get a map $g$ sending each element of $X$ to some $S_a$ containing it. We now argue:
>
> - Each $f\in\mathcal{F}$ is in $X$.
> - For each $f\in\mathcal{F}$ there is *exactly one* $a$ such that $g(f)=S_a$. *This is just the distinctness of the $S_a$s, which we brought about artificially above.*
>
> Let $h(f)$ denote that unique $a$. Then $h$ is a choice function for $\mathcal{F}$.

**My first proof:**

Let $W=\{\{\mathcal{F} \times A,a\} \mid a \in A \in \mathcal{F}\}$.

1. $\mathcal{F} \times A \neq b$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $b\in \bigcup \mathcal{F}$.

Assume that $\mathcal{F} \times A = b$ where $b \in B \in \mathcal{F}$, and that $a \in A$. Then $b \in B \in \{B\} \in \{\{B\},\{B,a\}\}=(B,a)\in \mathcal{F} \times A=b$. This contradicts to Axiom of Regularity.

2. We generate function $f$ as follows:

Apply this Theorem, there exists a function $g:\bigcup W \to W$ such that $a \in g(a) \in W$.

$f:\mathcal{F} \to \bigcup \mathcal{F}$ such that $f(A)=g(\mathcal{F} \times A) \setminus \{\mathcal{F} \times A\}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

**My second proof:**

Let $R(x)=\{A \in \mathcal{F} \mid x \in A\} \cup \{\mathcal{F} \times \{x\}\}$ and $W=\{R(x) \mid\ x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F}\}$.

1. $\mathcal{F} \times \{x\} \neq A$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F}$.

Assume that $\mathcal{F} \times \{x\} = A$ where $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F}$. Then $A \in \{A\} \in (A,x) \in \mathcal{F} \times \{x\}=A$. This contradicts to Axiom of Regularity.

Thus $\mathcal{F} \times \{x\}$ is a distinct indicator of $R(x)$. As a result, $R(a) \neq R(b)$ whenever $a \neq b$, or equivalently $R(x)$ is injective for all $x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F}$.

2. We generate function $f$ as follows:

Apply this Theorem, there exists a function $g:\bigcup W \to W$ such that $x \in g(x) \in W$. It is clear that $A \in W$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

Let $f(A)=R^{-1}(g(A))$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your questions : 
1. You didn't choose $x$ well enough then. Note that the $x$ is uniform, i.e. it's the *same* for all $a$'s. See 2. for why a good choice of $x$ suffices.

2. You want $(x,a)\notin\mathcal{F}$ so that if $(x,a) \in S_b$, either $(x,a) = (x,b)$, in which case $a=b$, or  $(x,a) = f$ for some $f\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $b\in f$; but in that second case $(x,a)\in \mathcal{F}$, which is not possible (due to the choice of $x$) : you are right this is probably a typo.
3. Your first proof seems correct (though it uses the axiom of regularity).
   For your second proof, note that it's not $R(x)$ that is injective, but rather $R$. Apart from that the second proof seems correct as well.

Comment: I'm very satisfied with your answer. You said *"though it uses the axiom of regularity"*, could you please show me how not to appeal to Axiom of Regularity?

Comment: Well I'm not sure your proof can do without appealing to it, but I'm pretty sure Noah's can, with an explanation on how to choose such an $x$. Indeed, a sufficient condition for $(x,a)\notin \mathcal{F}$ is $x\notin \bigcup\bigcup \mathcal{F}$. So it remains to be shown in ZF without regularity that, given any $A$, there is $x$ such that $x\notin A$. But that's easy, it's just Russell's paradox: put $x=\{y\in A\mid y\notin y\}$. With this applied to $A=\bigcup\bigcup\mathcal{F}$ you get $x\notin \bigcup\bigcup\mathcal{F}$, so $(x,a)\notin \mathcal{F}$ for any $a$

Comment: I got your point @Max, you have broadened my understanding of Noah's answer. Thank you so much :)